Extracting text from cloudwatch
I have a cloudwatch message format as follow:
POST /api/v1/order 200 123 bytes 456 bytes 458.000 ms Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14 (Java/17.0.12) { "orderId": "A123" } {"partnerOrderId": "B456", "createdDate": "2023-04-05"}

I am trying to extract the value of client, orderId and partnerOrderId out. But failing to do so.
Note: client can be anything after ms and before {
This is what I have tried.
fields @timestamp, @message, @client, @orderId, @partnerOrderId
| parse @message /(?<@client>(?<=ms\s).*)/
| parse @message /(?<@orderId>(?<=orderId\s).*)/
| parse @message /(?<@partnerOrderId>(?<=partnerOrderId\s).*)/

But this does not work. I am unsure how to trim it before { for client
and for orderId, and partnerOrderId there is totally empty result.
expected result
@timestamp @message  @client                   @orderId  @partnerOrderId
timestamp  message   Apache-HttpClient/4.5.14  A123     B456


Lookaround is not supported? Try simple patterns to see if it works: ms\s+([^(]+)\s+?

When you are using parse, you can use named capture groups for the value, and instead of using a lookbehind you can match what comes before it.
Note that when using .* you are matching the whole (rest of) the line.
To get the desired values only, you can make the pattern more specific.

In the pattern ms (?<@client>\S+) the \S+ part matches 1 or more non whitespace characters
In the pattern "orderId":\s*"(?<@orderId>[^"]+)" the [^"]+ part matches 1 or more characters other than a double quote. You could also for example make that more specific by using \w+

Example
fields @timestamp, @message, @client, @orderId, @partnerOrderId
| parse @message /ms (?<@client>\S+)/
| parse @message /"orderId":\s*"(?<@orderId>[^"]+)"/
| parse @message /"partnerOrderId":\s*"(?<@partnerOrderId>[^"]+)"/

Output

